# Is it possible develop or create class like python in R?

Tags: python, r, class, pointers

In python, there have a very clear structure about class, for example like blow.
The self concept is very convenience avoid the duplicate variable.
And it can also write the function to change the variable inside.

```
class object():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a
        self.b
        ......
    def addoneinside(self):
        self.a = a + 1
```

In R, I need to use `<-` change the value after return. Maybe I can use `%<>%` to do this.
But in python, I can do `object.addoneinside()`, then the `object.a` will become `2` automatically.

I really like r because the data process is really easy and intuition.
Is this possible to change R code style like python?

Comment: Your question seems to be not really about classes (which exist in R) but rather about writing functions that mutate their arguments. The answer to that is: it *can* be done (via R6 or non-standard evaluation) but it *shouldn’t* be done, almost ever. The fact that functions can’t mutate their arguments in R is an *advantage* (immutability in programming has various advantages over mutability), don’t subvert it. Python and R follow different styles here, and there’s little to be gained by writing R code inconsistently in a Python-like style.

Comment: While I agree with @KonradRudolph s comment, for completeness sake here is a link to a blogpost on R's 'next best' implementation of mutable class members [closures](https://www.r-bloggers.com/closures-in-r-a-useful-abstraction/)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Doesnt R6 exactly do what he wants? Why shouldnt it be done, if such a feature exists in a library?

Comment: @SebSta Because it’s unidiomatic, adds complexity, and gives up the advantages of immutability. R6 has its place, but it is definitely a niche use in the context of R. I’ve *never* needed it, and I do some pretty crazy stuff with R. It should definitely not be used for a general, user-facing R API: chances are, the API would be better without R6. A good example is ggplot2’s proto (which does essentially the same as R6), which is hidden away from the user (unless you want to extend ggplot2).